# How do I Import and Export components directly (without traversing path) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, module

I am attempting to refactor the import and exports in my react project.
Lets say I have project of this structure:

```
=react-project
===public
===src
=====components
=====page
=======Page1.js
=====services
=======ApiService.js
```

.
This is how I import ApiService in Page1.js currently:

```
// in Page1.js
import {ApiService} from '../services/ApiService'
```

---

This works but it will start to get messy as project gets larger and convoluted, so Im trying to refactor it and this is my new code structure:

```
=react-project
===public
===src
=====components
=====page
=======Page1.js
=====services
=======index.js
=======ApiService.js
```

```
//in index.js
export * from './ApiService'
```

and this is how i import ApiService from Page1.js now...

```
//in Page1.js
import {ApiService} from 'services'
```

However this doesnt work! Am I missing something? I want this `import {ApiService} from 'services'`  to be how it is like eventually. Such that I can import in the same way at any component or page.

Comment: Your folder is called `services` (plural) but you are importing from `service` (singular).

Comment: @UXNomaan sorry that was a typo. Updated. Im unable to import directly from 'services' though.

Comment: `'services'` this doesn't look like a path. Try changing it to `'./services'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yea my point is, how do i make it recognisable such that i dont have to use the path `'./services'` and instead i can call `'services'` anywhere

Comment: You would need to make it an npm module. It doesn’t need to be published, but it would need to be its own project.